# Hello World example not working on OS X

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am totally new to Android, and I am following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html). My problem is that the Adroid Emulator does not show the Hello World text, it just displays "ANDROID" on the center of the screen and no buttons works. Is this a know problem, how do I get it fixed?

Thank you

Comment: Your emulator is loading - give it time.

Comment: This question comes up alot. Might be a good idea for the owners to add it to http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sameer Segal said, the emulator does take a long time. First it will display "Android" in a small plain font, then it will go to a bigger, nicer, shining font, and then it will load the OS. After the OS has loaded, give it a few more seconds and it should go straight into the app you launched.

It takes a long time, but once you have it loaded you can leave it open and run your apps again and again. It will only take a few seconds each time from then on.

Comment: Never imagined it would take that long :)